# Lightweight HTTP/HTTPS server in C++ (not C)

Tags: c++, proxy

I need to build a lightweight http server for my application basically it's a server which listen to a port and outputs a status information on requests, https, other functionality. But I would like to know first if something like this existe in C++, for linux and open source.

Does anyone know a program like that?

Thanks.

EDIT: It should be able to support high load.

Comment: Just fix the part where it says "on requests __no high load__ ", so readers don't get confused.

Comment: @jweyrich: Edited, thanks for the advise. Sorry for the confusion. I mean that the application wouldn't have high load at beginning but it should be able to support high load.

Comment: What is the expected load? 100 clients per second? 1k/s? 10k/s? 100k/s?

Answer (score 6):

If you can use boost, the asio library provides an http [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). It does not use SSL, but asio can use OpenSSL very [easily](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html).

Comment: Given the new requirement, I think would be good to mention Asio can take advantage of async mechanisms like epoll (Linux-based), kqueue (BSD-based), and overlapped-IO (Windows). More infos [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle high loads I would suggest following:

1. Use **proper** web server with all goodies it comes with like Lighttpd, Nginx or Apache (in that order).

   It would do great job in serving static files and handle your application. And they are very lightweight.
2. Write an Application in C++ using proper web framework - [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sf.net) - that is designed for high loads
3. Connect Web Application to the server via FastCGI or SCGI protocol (in this order).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of CppCMS

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "C++ web application framework" shows things called CppCMS and something else called WT. That might get you started.

Or, as Sam already answered: boost.asio comes with a HTTP example that may be sufficient if your needs are simple. (Real HTTP request handling is actually surprisingly complex: http://webmachine.basho.com/diagram.html )

Answer (score 0):

See thttpd. Supposibly the fastest open source file server on all machines with a single CPU.

Answer (score -1):

If not using HTTPS, it's about a two hour exercise to write a static file server.

Comment: High-performance doesn't seem to be a requirement: "no high load" in the question.

Comment: This answer is no longer good due to changing requirements. However even a fork() based server can fill 100mbit ethernet these days.